# Files count aftet MassIndexer is HUGE for hibernate-search 3.4.0

Tags: indexing, lucene, hibernate-search, indexer

I use MassIndexer to index. After migrate to Hibernate-search 3.4 from 3.2.1.Final count of files is really really huge (with .cfs extension). Before it was OK. And the same time migrate onto lucene-core 3.1.0

Please, could somebody explain why it happened?

```
  MassIndexer massIndexe = fullTextSession.createIndexer(SearchLuceneDocument.class);

        massIndexe.purgeAllOnStart(true) // true by default, highly recommended
                .optimizeAfterPurge(true) // true is default, saves some disk space
                .optimizeOnFinish(true) // true by default
                .batchSizeToLoadObjects(100)
                .threadsForSubsequentFetching(15)
                .threadsToLoadObjects(10)
                .threadsForIndexWriter(4)
                .cacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE) // defaults to CacheMode.IGNORE
                .startAndWait();
```

Tanks to advance!

Artem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what filesystem are you on? It's known that some NFS leak file descriptors; in fact that's why we propose different alternatives for clustering - none of them involves NFS.
I'm not aware of bugs of us not closing the files during massindexer, but if you could contribute a test highlighting the error I'd be glad to look into it; post it on JIRA or on the hibernate forums, in the Search sections.
thanks